# Makefile for building library across multiple architectures

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I have a very basic makefile that has targets to build a static library or a dynamic library. It defaults to creating a static library.

I'd like to be able to build this library for multiple architectures. I'd like to be able to specify the architecture I'd like to build it for via the command line, so that it picks up everything else internally(value for CC, AR etc.).

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: You mean for cross compilation?

Comment: @kaylum Yes, I mean for cross compilation.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I'd suggest is to set environment variables for different architecture in the makefile and then define rules that will refer to the variables for that part of the architecture. Some common values can also be set and used elsewhere.

```
SPARCCC=/opt/SUNWspro/bin/cross-cc
GCC=/usr/bin/gcc
GCCDEBUG=/usr/bin/gcc
TAR=/usr/bin/tar

sparc: 
    @echo $(SPARCCC) -o a a.c
    @echo ${TAR} cvf a.tar a.*

i386 : 
    @echo $(GCC) -o a a.c
    @echo ${TAR} cvf a.tar a.*
    @echo $(GCCDBX)
```

There are two different targets here sparc and i386 and running those for the script above will yield results as below

```
$ make sparc
/opt/SUNWspro/bin/cc -o a a.c
/usr/bin/tar cvf a.tar a.c a.tar

$ make i386
/usr/bin/gcc -o a a.c
/usr/bin/tar cvf a.tar a.c a.tar
```